# Accidentally Deleted Branch On Github Desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I accidentally deleted a branch without pushing my commits, is there any way to get the branch back (with or without the commits)? I see the branch on GitHub but It is not letting me pull it up in Github desktop

These buttons are way to close to each other

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Look in the reflog — `git reflog` — for the most recent entry where HEAD was pointing to the branch. (You will probably know this because the entry above that will show you switching *away* from that branch.) `git switch --det <SHA>` of that entry. Now create the branch name again.

---

Example. We start with this:

```
* 31da420 (mybranch) c3
* 0ec170a c2
* cc73d1b c1
| * 7dcb9af (HEAD -> main) emptied c2
| * 7e2b31f c2
|/  
* 61bc628 three
* e4b07f5 two
* 9bfc0a6 one
```

We now accidentally delete `mybranch`:

```
% git branch -D mybranch
```

Darn. Let's explore the reflog:

```
% git reflog
7dcb9af (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from mybranch to main
31da420 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to 31da420
```

Since the first one says we moved *from mybranch*, the second one must *be* `mybranch`. So:

```
% git switch --det 31da420
% git switch -c mybranch
```

Done! To prove it, I'll switch to `main` and survey the situation again:

```
% git switch main
* 31da420 (mybranch) c3
* 0ec170a c2
* cc73d1b c1
| * 7dcb9af (HEAD -> main) emptied c2
| * 7e2b31f c2
|/  
* 61bc628 three
* e4b07f5 two
* 9bfc0a6 one
```

Exactly the same as before.

Comment: switched to the last commit before deletion, but says "cannot publish detached head" in GitHub desktop

Comment: Because you didn't do the last thing I said: create the branch name again.

Comment: create a new branch with the same name?

Comment: Look at the answer. I've enacted the entire scenario for you.

Comment: A branch _is_ a name. That's ultimately _all_ it is. It is a name for one commit. You threw away the name, and that's _all_ you threw away. Now you are creating that name again and attaching it to the same commit it was attached to when you threw it away. Result: everything is exactly the same as before.

Comment: I went through those commands, created a new branch but Github Desktop isn't recognizing the switch.

Comment: it also looks like all the commits that were not pushed are now gone?

Comment: Then you've checked out the wrong commit. If you committed while on a branch, the last commit you created leads back to the others.

Comment: I really am not interested in what GitHub Desktop says. Personally I'd advise throwing it away and learning to work at the command line. But that's just an opinion. I've demonstrated to you in my answer that this works.

Comment: Constructive solution!

Comment: Worked for me. This should be the accepted answer - this just saved me a bunch of time after I foolishly deleted a branch I hadn't pushed yet. Thank you @matt

Comment: @JimSkerritt The reflog is Git's Undo stack!